# Re: Unable to center div section

Tags: javascript, html

Newbie needs help as I am unable to center the following code by using either `<p align="center">` or `<div align="center">`.

My Code:

```
<div id="cp_widget_2445b6c4-0741-4027-9dbd-0ac3ba09af05">...</div>

<script type="text/javascript">
 var cpo = []; 
 cpo["_object"] = "cp_widget_2445b6c4-0741-4027-9dbd-0ac3ba09af05";     
 cpo["_fid"] = "AYEAnSOx19tA";
 var _cpmp = _cpmp || []; _cpmp.push(cpo);
 (function() { 
     var cp = document.createElement("script"); 
     cp.type = "text/javascript";
     cp.async = true; 
     cp.src = "//www.cincopa.com/media-platform/runtime/libasync.js";

     var c = document.getElementsByTagName("script")[0];
     c.parentNode.insertBefore(cp, c); 
 })(); 
</script>
```

Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: Create a working snippet for us so we can help out.

Answer (score 1):

Add css properties `display: block; margin: 0 auto` to the element.

You can also use flexbox. Add the following css properties -

`display: flex;
justify-content: center;
align-items: center;`

Comment: Is there something wrong with this? Plz help me understand

Comment: Not my downvote, but for a div, you don't even need the `display: block` part.